# Meaning of the following code snippet

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1

```
  MainVMBase.InstanceBase.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
       {
           if (serviceRequest != null && serviceRequest.Offset == 0)
           {
               Collection.Clear();
           }
           foreach (var attachments in attachmentsList)
           {
               Collection.Add(attachments);
           }
           base.SetResult(data);
       });
```

`I am newbie to the programming. what is exact meaning of the code     ""MainVMBase.InstanceBase.Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, () => "".Can anyone help me?

Comment: It's a very complex thing to explain to a person who's new to programming. And that statement seems incomplete. What's after the `=>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code instructs the [`Dispatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.core.coredispatcher) referenced by the `MainVMBase.InstanceBase.Dispatcher` property to execute the code between `{` and `}` with a priority of `Normal`. For details about what all this "crazy stuff" means, read on MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms741870(v=vs.110).aspx

This topic assumes you have an understanding of threading and other rather advanced concepts in computer programming in general. If you're not familiar with these, I suggest you don't try to jump steps and learn everything from the beginning by doing `Hello, World!` type of applications and reading thru introductory material about programming in general.